# how to quick up the process of displaying images in React coming from backend (Django Rest)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios, setinterval

I have an api in django and I am calling it from react front end, the thing is the api have to be called infinitely and in every request from react, there is always new image came from request's response.The response is coming in a good speed but the speed of the reactjs displaying the images is really slow, I am displaying the images without reloading the whole component and I want to display it without reloading.

```
runInfinite=()=>{

        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/faceapp/process_image/')
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({baseimage: res.data}, () => {
                    console.log(this.state.baseimage)
                })
            });
    };

render() {

        if (this.state.flag){
            setInterval(()=> { this.runInfinite(); },1000);
        }
        return (
                  <div>
                            {this.state.baseimage?<img  src={"data:image/png;base64," +  this.state.baseimage}/>:<h1>Hello</h1>}
                  </div>

        );
    }
}
```

What can I do so React can display images in the same speed as the response is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably nothing that react can do in this case. You'll have to optimise the image and their dimensions as required on the page itself.

Like, You can start with checking the resolution needed.

E.g. There is no need to load an image of 4000*3000 in a placeholder of 400*300.

Comment: Thanks your answer worked for me, I have resize the images and are now working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I can hardly imagine that React is too slow for rendering an image. Please validate where you're actual delay is coming from.

Other than that, you have a potential DoS issue.

Combining `setInterval` (never use `setInterval`) with an IO request (especially for processing data) is a recipe for error. What happens when your server takes more than `1000`ms to respond? Answer: multiple requests start stacking up and slowing down the program to a hold. Might that be what's actually happening?

Avoid this behavior by

- Initialing a request for a `Promise` or other callback.
- When completed, run logic based on output.
- Then reschedule request after all of this has been completed.